# How to use SimpleTimeLimiter (Guava) with Vaadin

Tags: java, java-8, vaadin, guava, vaadin8

I'm trying to call some code within the vaadin framework which is longer running that will update the screen using push, however if the process is taking too long I want to be able to cancel it.

With that in mind I'm trying to use Guava's `SimpleTimeLimiter` class but no matter what I do I can't seem to stop the Vaadin process from stopping. I've tried both to put the `SimpleTimeLimiter` inside `UI.getCurrent().access()` method and outside of it but they both just continue to execute the process even if `SimpleTimeLimiter` throws a `TimeoutException`. However if I use the same code with a normal thread it seems to work...

```
public static void limitExecutionTime(Consumer<UI> lambda)
{
    UI currentUI = UI.getCurrent();

    UI.getCurrent().access(() ->
    {
        try
        {
            SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).callWithTimeout(new Callable<Void>()
            {
                @Override
                public Void call()
                {
                    // This is needed to deal how Vaadin 8 handles UI's
                    UI.setCurrent(currentUI);
                    lambda.accept();
                    return null;
                }
            }, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        } catch (TimeoutException | InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            NotificationUtils.showError("Execution took beyond the maximum allowed time.");
            currentUI.push();
        }
    });
}
```

In the above code if the method takes more than 1 second it will throw a `TimeoutException` and put up the notification window. However it will continue to execute the lambda.

As a result I've tried to do the opposite and put `UI.getCurrent().access()` in the `public Void call()` method but this had the exact same result...

Answer (score 3):

You should call `UI.access` after your background task is ready to update it with some data. You use `access` method to do changes on the page that the user is viewing.

**Background task execution**

In your example, you are missing a way to pass task cancellation message to `call` method. In order to prepare for task cancellation from external event (for example cancel button click) then you need to take this into account in inside the task. The following example shows how you can offer cancel method using `Future.cancel`.

```
private void onCancelClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
    // This method is called from Vaadin UI thread. We will signal
    // background task thread to stop.
    futureResult.cancel(true);
}
```

Inside the actual task this can be handled in the following ways

```
private void simulateLongAndSlowCalculation() {
    while (moreWorkTodo) {
        if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            doSomeBlockingCallThatCanBeInterrupted();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**Starting task and UI.access**

When starting task then view should create task and submit it to executor service.

```
private void onButtonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {
    // This runTask creates important link to current UI and the background task.
    // "this" object in these onTask methods is the UI object that we want
    // to update. We need to have someway to pass UI object to background
    // thread. UI.getCurrent() could be a parameter that is passed to the
    // task as well.
    Future<String> futureResult = taskService.runTask(
            this::onTaskDone,
            this::onTaskCancel,
            this::onTaskProgress);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(futureResult);
    progressDialog.show();
}
```

Now UI.access method is only needed when we want to update UI. In this example, that can happen in the following cases

1. Task completed successfully
2. Task progress was updated
3. Task got cancelled

Note that all of the following methods `this` refers to the UI object that started the task. So we are updating the correct UI with result and not some other user's UI.

You should not need to call UI.setCurrent in your code.

```
private void onTaskProgress(double progress) {
    logger.info("onTaskProgress: {}", progress);
    access(() -> progressDialog.setProgress(progress));
}

private void onTaskCancel() {
    logger.info("onTaskCancel");
    access(() -> {
        progressDialog.close();
        setResult("Cancelled");
    });
}

private void onTaskDone(String result) {
    logger.info("onTaskDone");
    access(() -> {
        progressDialog.close();
        setResult(result);
    });
}
```

**Example project**

I pushed another project to github that shows how to cancel a background task from cancel button:

https://github.com/m1kah/vaadin-background-task

*Edit: Added sections about background tasks and UI.access. Updated example project link to another example.*

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. Basically I can't find a way to kill a UI.access task after x amount of time.In other words I ran UI.getCurrent().access() in the public Void call method instead of the way it's displayed, and it was the same result, the access() continued even if there was a TimeoutException.

Comment: @StephaneGrenier I have updated my answer with more on the topic + created better example project :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed example and sample code, it's really appreciated. I guess my main concern is what is the difference between you're code and Guava's SimpleTimeLimiter? As in it is there a lot of re-inventing of the wheel? If I understand your code correctly you're basically polling to see if its time to interrupt?

Comment: The other issue is that you're assuming the long calculation is in a loop, or that it's a loop of work. Unfortunately in my case I'm sending the code off to a report renderer which means that I have no ability to poll within the long calculation. I basically have to kill the thread outside of a calculation loop :(

Comment: You can cancel task by calling future.cancel(true); The thread running the task will be then interrupted. Whatever your task is that can then check for interrupted status and stop.

Comment: I guess my question is how is this different then using Guava's SimpleTimeLimiter class? Aren't you basically replicating the functionality? In other words if it's the exact same logic then I'd rather delegate that to Guava than have to maintain and support it myself because of the potential for all kinds of weird concurrency bugs...

Comment: `SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout` is a blocking call. You would not want to call this directly from UI thread because UI will be unresponsive and will timeout in Vaadin after 2 min of blocking. So using SimpleTimeLimiter is not that simple because we want to start background task and have UI thread to return response to browser without further delays :)